# Javascript: calculate 3.4% of total plus €0.35

Tags: paypal, addition

I have a form where people enter an amount to pay and are then sent to paypal when they click 'submit'. I want this form to automatically add 3.4% of the total plus €0.35 to the amount to cover the cost of the paypal fees. I looked around both stackoverflow and elsewhere and found answers that were so specific about slightly different issues that I couldn't customise them to this particular case.

Doea anyone have an answer? I'm sure it's something that many people need at one point or another.

Comment: show us your code and where did you get stuck

Answer (score 1):

You may try this: `total + (total / 100.0 * 3.4) + 0.35`.

Make sure you do this calculation on JavaScript only to previously display the result to the user, and do it again on your backend, because anyone with average JavaScript knowledge could bypass it if you calculate it on client side and then send to server.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you want to do is multiply times 1.034 (that's 100% + 3.4%, gives 103.4%; divide by 100%, and you get a proportion of 1.034). Then add your 0.35 EURO.

I don't know what language your form is written in, but if you're at this point, you should be able to figure things out. If you can't figure things out from there, you need to post what code you have (if you have the right to release it) or at least tell us what language or program you are using to set this all up, if you cannot post your code.

In summary, if you have a variable SUBTOTAL, your NETTOTAL will be:

```
NETTOTAL = SUBTOTAL * 1.034 + 0.35
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I'm a designer not a programmer so I'm just using html along with some paypal code I found a while ago that will allow someone to freely enter their payment amount. The code is:

[cont'd below]

Comment: <form id="payPalForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"> <input name="item_number" type="hidden" value="Payment" /> <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" /><input id="item_name" name="item_name" size="45" type="text" /> <br /> Amount: <br />€ <input id="amount" name="amount" size="45" type="text" /> <br /> <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>